# How can I change index.php to index1.php in joomla?

Tags: php, url, joomla

I want to change index.php to index1.php in joomla eg :
Now it is `www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_content.....`
I want change to :

```
www.domain.com/index1.php?option=com_content.........
```

Comment: Is there a question in here somewhere?

Comment: is there a particular reason to change the standard convention?

Comment: Yes I want to display some information at index.php and I can't put joomla in subfolder.

Comment: I would first try changing the default document of the webserver to index1.php and putting the display info there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Joomla, index.php is the starting point for every single "page" that can be displayed by the CMS. Trying to change that would require extensive changes to the Joomla core. I would highly recommend not doing that, you will regret it. You have a couple of options -

1. Use index.html or maybe default.php for the other info you want. You can change the order that the web server uses the default file so that one of those comes up before index.php
2. Put Joomla in a subdirectory